# Passing default parameter value to view method in django is not working

Tags: django

I am very new to Django.
I am trying to use an URL with optional parameter, 
If I pass an URL including the optional Parameter, everything works as expected, but when I try to use an URL without the optional parameter I am getting a 404 page not found error.

My ***urls.py*** file content

```
from coffeehouse.stores import views as stores_views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^store/(?P<store_id>\d+)/',stores_views.details)
]
```

***stores/views.py*** file content

```
def details(request, store_id='1'):
store_info={
    'store_id':store_id
}
return render(request, 'stores/details.html',store_info)
```

I am unable to figure out why the default parameter is not considered.

> I am using Django 1.11, I am not sure if there is anything related to the version of Django.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help someone in the future.

I fixed the issue. I have almost forgot to include one line in the ***urls.py*** file.

This change fixed my issue.

```
from coffeehouse.stores import views as stores_views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^store/$',stores_views.details)
    url(r'^store/(?P<store_id>\d+)/',stores_views.details)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could provide 2 different URLs, one to handle url with parameter, the other one to handle url without parameter

> Don't forget to add the `$` sign at the end of URLs

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^store/$',stores_views.details)
    url(r'^store/(?P<store_id>\d+)/$',stores_views.details)
]
```

If you visit the site with `127.0.0.1:8000/store` Django will first try to find the first pattern that matches. In our case, the first will match.

If you visit the site with `127.0.0.1:8000/store/1` Django will first try to find the first pattern that matches. The first one will never match, so Django will then try the second, and of course it will match.